# find the subjects that are connecting entites in DBpedia with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm extracting entities from a text, most of the time I get multiple entites, for example `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/NASA>`, `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/IPhone>` and `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.>`

These two entites, don't share the same `dct:subject` is there a way to query a path to get a list of the subjects connect my entities?

My goal is to create kind of a "page rank", to find the most relevant subjects for a given entity.

Preferably with a counter how many steps are between them.

I've tried to brute force it, start with a entity, get all the subjects and then get all entites for the subject and so on but the queries are starting to get enormous.

Comment: `select distinct ?cat {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> dct:subject/skos:broader* ?cat .
dbr:IPhone dct:subject/skos:broader* ?cat .
}` but for sure you might get a timeout as this can become pretty expensive

Comment: In Virtuoso, you can also try to add a restriction on the length of the path: `select distinct ?cat {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> dct:subject/skos:broader{1,3} ?cat .
dbr:IPhone dct:subject/skos:broader{1,3} ?cat .
}`

Comment: A more compact version: `select distinct ?cat {
 ?cat ^skos:broader{1,3}/^dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.>, dbr:IPhone
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Springing from @AKSW's comments...

One option, without limit on length of `skos:broader` path lengths, which will exceed resource consumption limits on the public DBpedia endpoint, but which could be run on a private instance ([in the cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK) or wherever) where you may relax those limits --

```
PREFIX   dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX   dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX  skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?cat 
WHERE
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.>
        dct:subject/skos:broader*  ?cat . 
    dbr:IPhone 
        dct:subject/skos:broader*  ?cat . }
```

The succinct option, using Virtuoso-specific syntax (based on an early draft of SPARQL Property Paths) to limit the path's length (here requiring at least 1 `skos:broader` and permitting up to 3) --

```
PREFIX   dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX   dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX  skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?cat 
WHERE
  { ?cat
       ^skos:broader{1,3}/^dct:subject
           <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> , 
           dbr:IPhone 
  }
```

Another succinct option, this time using standard SPARQL [Property Paths syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) to limit the path's length --

```
PREFIX   dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX   dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX  skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?cat 
WHERE
  { ?cat
       ^skos:broader/^skos:broader?/^skos:broader?/^dct:subject
           <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> , 
           dbr:IPhone 
  }
```

You can also use 2 statements with the uninverted paths in the WHERE clauses, first in Virtuoso-specific form --

```
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> 
       dct:subject/skos:broader{1,3}   ?cat  .
    dbr:IPhone 
       dct:subject/skos:broader{1,3}   ?cat  .
  }
```

-- and then in standard SPARQL --

```
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc.> 
       dct:subject/skos:broader/skos:broader?/skos:broader?   ?cat  .
    dbr:IPhone 
       dct:subject/skos:broader/skos:broader?/skos:broader?   ?cat  .
  }
```